# Rails route match different action in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have the following routes declared in my file:

```
resources :reservations do
  collection do
    resources :check_in do
      get :charges
      get :reservation_details
    end
  end
end
```

And these actions in my check_in controller:

```
  def charges
    @charge = Charge.new
    @items = Product.where(hotel: current_hotel).includes(:hotel)
    calculate_totals(reservation)
    currency_divider
  end

  def reservation_details
    charges
  end
```

Both actions perform the same operations, but have a different view (html) file.

Can I somehow redirect the '/reservation_details' to the charges action in the check_in controller but keeping the same URL? I mean, to save me from writing the action code in the controller (which just calls the other action).

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
resources :reservations do
  collection do
    resources :check_in do
      get :charges
      get "/reservation_details", to: redirect('/charges')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but this redirects me to root_path/charges.
Also, I don't want to be redirected to another URI, just tu use the same action in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
resources :reservations do
  collection do
    resources :check_in do
      get :charges
      get :reservation_details, to: 'check_in#charges'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Almost! It redirects well (keeping the URI on the browser) but it renders the "charges" view, not the "reservation_details" view.
I'm starting to think to this is not possible.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now.  To do that, your shared controller method would need to know which route called it, which you could technically do with `request.env['PATH_INFO']`... but I really wouldn't go down that road.  I think it's much cleaner to just have `#charges` and `#reservation_details` methods in your controller, even if they do the same thing. You can always DRY it up with a helper method that contains the shared code.